# App Crashes while trying to view code

Tags: bug, android-app

Steps to Reproduce

1. Tap faster on the code.
2. or Tap once on a huge code.

but happens only when 
**setupForGeneric()** is called, might be a bug related to http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=12987

```
private void setupForCode()
  {
String str = getIntent().getStringExtra("com.stackexchange.marvin:code_block");
PrettyWebView localPrettyWebView = (PrettyWebView)findViewById(R.id.code);
localPrettyWebView.setPostBody("<pre><code>" + TextUtils.htmlEncode(str) + "</pre></code>", false);
localPrettyWebView.setBackgroundColor("#eeeeee");
}

private void setupForGeneric()
{
String str = getIntent().getStringExtra("com.stackexchange.marvin:web_url");
PrettyWebView localPrettyWebView = (PrettyWebView)findViewById(R.id.code);
localPrettyWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
localPrettyWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
localPrettyWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
localPrettyWebView.loadUrl(str);
localPrettyWebView.setBackgroundColor("#eeeeee");
}
```

**Log**

```
09-05 03:54:30.312: E/AndroidRuntime(26264): FATAL EXCEPTION: WebViewCoreThread

09-05 03:09:39.522: E/Crittercism(18318): java.lang.NullPointerException: [v0.1.22] 
09-05 03:09:39.522: E/Crittercism(18318):   at android.content.ComponentName.<init>(ComponentName.java:75)
09-05 03:09:39.522: E/Crittercism(18318):   at android.content.Intent.<init>(Intent.java:3156)
09-05 03:09:39.522: E/Crittercism(18318):   at com.stackexchange.marvin.ui.ViewPopupActivity.showCode(ViewPopupActivity.java:25)
09-05 03:09:39.522: E/Crittercism(18318):   at com.stackexchange.marvin.ui.question.QuestionFragment$1.onCodeClicked(QuestionFragment.java:67)
09-05 03:09:39.522: E/Crittercism(18318):   at com.stackexchange.marvin.ui.common.PrettyWebView$WebAppInterface.codeClicked(PrettyWebView.java:197)
09-05 03:09:39.522: E/Crittercism(18318):   at android.webkit.WebViewCore.nativeTouchUp(Native Method)
09-05 03:09:39.522: E/Crittercism(18318):   at android.webkit.WebViewCore.nativeTouchUp(Native Method)
09-05 03:09:39.522: E/Crittercism(18318):   at android.webkit.WebViewCore.access$4000(WebViewCore.java:59)
09-05 03:09:39.522: E/Crittercism(18318):   at android.webkit.WebViewCore$EventHub$1.handleMessage(WebViewCore.java:1449)
09-05 03:09:39.522: E/Crittercism(18318):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-05 03:09:39.522: E/Crittercism(18318):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-05 03:09:39.522: E/Crittercism(18318):   at android.webkit.WebViewCore$WebCoreThread.run(WebViewCore.java:790)
09-05 03:09:39.522: E/Crittercism(18318):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Comment: This looks **so** much like a [so] post...

Comment: But this is related to bug in `android-app` Feel free to moderate the question if required.

Comment: *Resists urge to utterly destroy post as a programming question.*

Comment: @VenomVendor But yes, it's fine here.

Comment: Haha - you're correct, @ven. [Undo said it best](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/195825/app-crashes-while-trying-to-view-code?noredirect=1#comment617581_195825) :P

Comment: @Lix , @ Undo, do edit the question if it's too much info, am regular user of SO & totally new here.

Comment: @ven - You've done the right thing. This is the correct place to post bug reports. We see a lot of questions posted here on [meta] that should be on [so]. The big give-away usually is a wall of code in a meta post (which shouldn't *usually* be there). It just caught me off guard :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was a bug related to being able to click multiple times on the code block and have infinite code popups.  This should be resolved in v0.1.23

Please let me know if you continue to have this issue after the next build.

Comment: still the same `09-05 13:57:14.572: E/AndroidRuntime(4752): java.lang.NullPointerException: [v0.1.23]` and when I double tap, am getting twice.

You might not see is the delay in popup if you are testing in highend devices, test it in windows/linux emulator or low end devices.

Disable second click immediately if clicked on `codeView`. 

ClickedOnCodeView >> disableClickOnCodeView >> isActivityPausedAfterTap >> isActivityResumedAfterTap >> enableClick. Bulletproof.