# Few Feature Requests in Android App

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-completed, android-app

1. Add Padding to the **code** inside webview.
2. Clicking code in a post `n` times brings the popup window `n` times. This ***might be*** a reason [for this crash](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/195825/185258). Because the code is being read line by line & printed, crash could be reproducible with big code.
3. Trying to scroll to answer tab brings notifications, I always scroll from the
   right-most to scroll to right and vice-versa. Not sure how many
   users scroll in the centre.
4. **Clickable Tags** as in SO.
5. **AutoSuggest Tags** instead of throwing error while trying to post.
6. Remove Junk characters at the bottom of **help**:
   [image]
7. Change "help" to *about* or *info* in menu. This page doesn't really help, it's info about the app.

Comment: Great bug reports - keep them coming.  I've fixed #2 but won't mark this completed until we've addressed all of these issues.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Work in progress:

1. [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) – this and some other CSS improvements for questions and answers are in 0.1.27
2. [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) in 0.1.23
3. [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) in 0.1.24
4. [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) – tags are now clickable on the post
5. [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) duplicate of [Make tag selection more seamless and less error-prone on Android app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191412/posting-questions-make-tag-selection-more-seamless-and-less-error-prone)
6. [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) in 0.1.27 – we were reading past the end of a stream there
7. [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) – changed to "about"